# angular directives not working

Tags: angularjs

```
**Hello.html**
```

html code of what i want to do by making a directive

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="world.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />

<body ng-app="myApp">

<record></record>
</body>

**world.js**
```

i just make a directive but it's not working can anyone please find out my errors

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive("rec",function()
{
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        templateUrl:'record.html',
        controller:function($scope) {
         $scope.records = [
                {
                "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
                "Country" : "Germany"
                 }, {
                "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
                "Country" : "Sweden"
                 },{
                "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
                "Country" : "Mexico"
                },{
                "Name" : "Ernst Handel",
                "Country" : "Austria"
                }
        ],controllerAs:'records'
    }
    };
});

**record.html**
```

this is a new file record.html which i made to separate my working load but chrome is not showing it . can you please find out my errors for correction

```
<table  border="1">
<tr ng-repeat="x in records">
  <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
  <td>{{x.Country}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: replace `<record></record>` to `<rec></rec>` in your html code as your directive name is `rec`

Comment: still not working sir...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `controllerAs` is inside `controller` it should be outside like below

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive("rec",function()
{
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        templateUrl:'record.html',
        controller:function($scope) {
             $scope.records = [
             {
                "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
                "Country" : "Germany"
             }, {
            "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
            "Country" : "Sweden"
             },{
            "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
            "Country" : "Mexico"
            },{
            "Name" : "Ernst Handel",
            "Country" : "Austria"
            }
           ]},
        /*this should be outside of controller*/
        controllerAs:'records'
    };
});
```

and your directive call in html must be directive name as

```
<rec></rec>
```

See working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BerrNmOHXVbGOo19v5h0?p=preview)

Comment: glad to help you sir :).

Answer (score 0):

You directive name is wrong, it should be `record` instead of `rec`:

```
app.directive("record",function() {...});
```

So it matches an element `<record></record>`. Angular is trying to find a `<rec></rec>` instead.